# Is there any way to guarantee order of execution? Or is there any way to cancel currently executing scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an auto-complete-like feature on a text box.

```
textBox.addKeyUpHandler(textBoxLookupHandler)
```

### What happens

If the user is typing relatively quickly, say `a` `b`, it seems the following happens.

1. The handler for `a` is invoked.
2. The handler for `ab` is invoked.
3. `ab` returns fewer results. Because of this, it returns *before* the handler for `a`.
4. The handler for `a` then returns many results.

So in the end, the user typed `ab`, but they are being shown the results for `a` because the results for `a` overwrote the results for `ab`.

### Possible solutions

If I could write some client-side scripting, I know how I would handle this issue. But since I'm using UiApp, I can't do that.

1. Guarantee order of execution of GAS (I'm sure this isn't possible/is a ridiculous request)
2. Have some method in GAS to cancel all other currently running scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GAS has a [Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_lock) that will guarantee order of execution for you. See the Google Apps Developer Blog "[Concurrency and Google Apps Script](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.ca/2011/10/concurrency-and-google-apps-script.html)" entry.

Your handler should look something like this:

```
function textBoxLookupHandler(e) {
  var lock = LockService.getPrivateLock(); // Lock for just this user
  lock.waitLock(15000);  // wait max 15 seconds before exception.

  // Do whatever you used to do...

  lock.releaseLock();
  return app;
}
```